# Javascript - Autocomplete select with inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

i want something like this in an input of different stuff with a quantity:

[image: example]

Is a autocomplete select with a deletable list and an input at the end, like a small shopping cart; by the way, i try to look it like a shopping cart with no result

In the image i am using [maggisuggest](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/) but it has a problem with the input at the end, again with zero results of fix that problem

Any suggestions?, is for a webpage in RoR, so i can use javascript, jquery, gems, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a typeahead plugin component.

HTML select elements can not take user input, they simply allow the user to select from a set of predefined values.  You can alter the values in the list dynamically, but that is not really what you want to do.

Look at using something like [twitter typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/).